# Rake fails on creation of a new Ruby on Rails application

Tags: ruby, rake, bundler, ruby-on-rails-4

On the command line, when I go to create a new Ruby on Rails application, it fails on:

```
run bundle install
```

It says:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...

ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
An error occurred while installing rake (10.1.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rake -v '10.1.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

After doing what it asks (which doesn't produce any error), it says gem successfully installed. I've tried reinstalling bundler and it says one gem installed.

I'm following the steps from the Ruby on Rails tutorial, but I might have some lingering garbage from before on my computer from other coding.

How can I fix this problem?

I am Using Ruby 2.0.0 and Ruby on Rails 4.

Comment: What encoding is your Gemfile in?

Comment: Also, try removing each of the gems individually and then running the command. This can be caused by a bad gem.

Comment: @Screenmutt can you tell me how to find that out? How can I remove each individually?

Comment: Take a look at your **Gemfile** file. And remove each gem in there piece by piece and try to run `bundle install`. See which one you remove actually turns out to make bundler work.

Comment: ^ Exactly. And generally your text editor will tell you the encoding.